# Calculating distances in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, coordinates, distance

So I'm using QGIS 2.6.0 and I have a CSV (converted into a *.shp*) with two geometry columns, I want to create a new column with the distance between the two geometries:

```
shot.lat    shot.lon    haul.lat    haul.lon
57.563      -12.986     57.534      -12.985
57.7        -13.304     57.67       -13.299
57.611      -13.529     57.582      -13.538
57.594      -13.294     57.565      -13.315
57.432      -13.314     57.402      -13.304
57.339      -13.053     57.311      -13.072
```

I am trying to use the function geometry function `distance()` with the following expression:

```
distance(geomFromWKT('POINT("shot.lon" "shot.lat")'), geomFromWKT('POINT("haul.lon" "haul.lat")'))
```

This should then create a new field with the distance between the points. When it runs though, it just returns `NULL`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

You need to construct your string properly. Instead of:

```
'POINT("shot.lon" "shot.lat")'
```

Try:

```
'POINT(' + "shot.lon" + ' ' + "shot.lat" +')'
```

EDIT - However - for your example, that will only give you distance in degrees. This will work for projected coordinates (UTM, for example) but not decimal degrees.

Comment: Will `distance()` return correct result for the degrees input? `distance:         returns the minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between
                 two geometries in projected units`

Comment: No, definitely won't - was suggesting corrected code in a hurry, forgot to add that part.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the formula. When you paste this formula you can end up with an error `Parser Error: Eval Error: Cannot convert POINT(' to double`. It should with string concatenation `||` like `distance(geom_from_wkt('POINT(' + "X1" || ' ' || "Y1" + ')'), geom_from_wkt('POINT(' + "X2" || ' ' || "Y2" +')'))`