# Calculating distance betweeen classified points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, distance, qgsexpression

I got two sets of points.

1. The first set has a unique `"ID"`
2. The second set references to this `"ID"` (one-to-many).

So I merged the two sets. Now every point in the joined table has the `"X"` and `"Y"` coordinates from the related first set.

```
Name;ID;X;Y;X_2;Y_2;Distance
```

Every `"X"` and `"Y"` is unique but `"X_2"` and `"Y_2"` repeats from a given set.

Now I would like to calculate the distance between `(X,Y)` and `(X_2,Y_2)` in the new column for each row.

I tried `distance()` but I'm way too new in Python to get it working.

I also tried some tools like Distance Matrix, but I got results for all distances (or to the number defined) but not only to the distances in one row. Or between Points sharing the same `"ID"`.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: The software is QGIS

Comment: This topic [Calculate distance between two points with QGIS 2.14.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203398/calculate-distance-between-two-points-with-qgis-2-14-0) can also help you

Comment: Yes, thanks. Ive seen it. I cant install "Connect Points". I got QGIS 3.0.3. I cant find the Plug-In in the menu plus I cant install the download. As I understood the post (i read before asking my question) its not matching my problem perfectly. Im modifying a few 100k features. And Im looking for a quick and stable solution. So maybe a short python script could help me?

Comment: Thank you for posting another helpful topic! But I already read this topic (I read a lot of topics before posting here). Its not fixing my problem :(

Comment: I already tried "( geomFromWKT('POINT(' + "X" + ' ' + "Y" +')') , geomFromWKT('POINT(' + "X_2" + ' ' + "Y_2" +')'))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), please try:

```
distance(make_point("X", "Y"), make_point("X_2", "Y_2"))
```

The function [`distance()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#distance):

> Returns the minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two
> geometries in projected units.

---

Another formula which can lead to the answer is:

```
distance(geom_from_wkt('POINT(' + "X1" || ' ' || "Y1" + ')'), geom_from_wkt('POINT(' + "X2" || ' ' || "Y2" +')'))
```

---

P.S. To check whether the calculated distances are correct, you can apply the [Measure length](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#measuring) tool, see the image below.

[image: Measure_length_tool]

---

**References:**

- [How to calculate distances in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121972/how-to-calculate-distances-in-qgis-field-calculator)
- [Calculating distance between two points with QGIS 2.14.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203398/calculate-distance-between-two-points-with-qgis-2-14-0)
- [Measuring distance between points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245524/measuring-distance-between-points-using-qgis)